# SML - static scope doesn't cause any error while using exceptions

Tags: exception, programming-languages, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Given the following code :

```
exception E of int;
fun g(y) = raise E(y);
fun f(x) = 
    let 
      exception E of real;
      fun z(y)= raise E(y);
    in 
      x(3.0);
      z(3)
    end;
f(g);
```

When executing the code in SML I get :

```
stdIn:216.8-216.12 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: real
  operand:         int
  in expression:
    z 3
```

That's fine - I understand that the line `z(3);` causes an error , since `z` throws `int` instead of `real` .

But my problem is with the line `x(3.0);` , why doesn't it cause an error ?

From my understanding , `x` is `g(y)` , then when we execute `x(3.0)` we actually execute `g(3.0)` , but `g` throws only exceptions of type `int` , but we passed to `g` the value `3.0` ,hence `g` would throw a `real` value , so it's supposed to be a violation , doesn't it ?

I'd appreciate if someone can explain why no error is happening when executing `x(3.0)` .

Thanks

**EDIT:**

When I remove `z(3);` , meaning :

```
- fun f(x) =
=     let
=       exception E of real;
=       fun z(y)= raise E(y);
=     in
=       x(3.0)
=
=     end;
val f = fn : (real -> 'a) -> 'a
- f(g);
```

The output is :

```
stdIn:11.1-11.5 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: real -> 'Z
  operand:         int -> 'Y
  in expression:
    f g
-
```

So , as U can see , in both cases we'll get error .

Hence , I'm back at square one : why when both `x(3.0)` and `z(3)` appear (see code 1 , the first code posted at the beginning of the post) one after the other , why does SML only refers to the error that the second line (`z(3);`) caused , and not to the error that 
the first line caused (`x(3.0);`) .

10x again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement Jesper's excellent answer: In other words, there is nothing wrong with the call to `x` inside `f`. If you remove the erroneous call to `z`, and then type `f` into an SML prompt, then you should see that the type system has inferred the type

```
(real -> 'a)  -> 'a
```

for it. That type is perfectly fine, it is merely the *call* to `f` later on in your program that is ill-typed. because `g` does not match the parameter type `real -> 'a` as required.

Comment: 1) Thanks for the answer . 2) I'm sorry ,but I still can't understand why `x(3.0);` doesn't cause any error . If I remove the line `z(3)` , and run the code without it , then I will get error for `x(3.0);` , since it throws real instead of int . I'd appreciate any clarifications .

Comment: @ron: Hm, I don't know what exactly you tried, but entering ``fun f(x) = let   ... in x(3.0) end;`` alone does not cause any errors.

Comment: Also, you can call it without problem with e.g., ``f(fn x => x)`` and get back 3.0. The function itself does not throw anything.

Comment: Please see the edited post (#EDIT at the bottom of the post) .

Comment: Let's go over it again. There are 2 errors in your program: (1) the call ``z(3)`` (``z`` has type ``real -> 'a`` but is passed an argument of type ``int``); (2) the call ``f(g)`` (``f``, when ignoring the 1st error, would have a type like I showed above, but is passed a function of type ``int -> 'a``). The local call ``x(3.0)`` is not flagged as an error, because it _isn't_ one. It is perfectly well-typed when you pass an appropriate function for ``x`` (see above). So all SML has to do is preventing you from _calling_ ``f`` with something that violates the typing requirements for ``x``.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the fact that x is a function that is passed along to f, thus when typing the function f, it will always give the correct type to the argument x, as it is not bound by anything. The fact that you are have a function application `f(g)` right after plays no role when inferring the types of the function `f`.

If we move the local function `z` outside the definition of `f`, we end up with something a lot simpler, which will type

```
exception R of real;
fun z(y)= raise R (y);

exception I of int;
fun g(y) = raise I (y);

fun f(i, r) = (i(3.0); r(3))
```

However when we then call `f(g,z)` we end up with the following error, as the two functions aren't of the correct type

```
- f(g, z);
stdIn:78.1-78.8 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (real -> 'Z) * (int -> 'Y)
  operand:         (int -> 'X) * (real -> 'W)
  in expression:
    f (g,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial misunderstanding stemmed from not understanding when the type error was detected. Standard ML is a strongly STATICALLY typed language. This means that the type checking is all done at compile time, when the function is first read by the interpreter, not at run-time. This means that the type error is generated before the code is ever executed, which Jesper correctly pointed out. The two type errors are exactly where Jesper indicated, in the f(g) expression and the z(3) expression. There is nothing wrong with the expression x(3.0) when the expression is compiled. There would only be a problem there if static type checking did not prevent the program from running at all. A dynamically typed language like Python would allow this program to run and raise an exception where Ron suggests when the x(3.0) expression was evaluated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Scott, not sure what you mean by this does not answer the question. It certainly does. The program doesn't run because it is incorrectly typed. Ron wondered why it did not reach the intended exception. The answer is the program never ran. Does that make sense to you? It does to me. Is there an issue here other than providing a correct answer?